# iterating with while loop: adds slightly more than I'm asking for

Tags: python, loops, types, while-loop

I'm working in Python. So before I start my loop, I have `s = 3` and `ds = 0.2`. I have a while loop ending at `s = 5`. At the end of the loop, `s += ds`. At each iteration of the loop I'm plotting my graph for that time, and values weren't *exactly* right, and when I included the times in title of the graphs, I saw they're not exact.

I'm getting this:

```
3
3.2
3.4000000000000004
3.6000000000000005
3.8000000000000007
4.000000000000001
4.200000000000001
4.400000000000001
4.600000000000001
4.800000000000002
```

What's with that? How can I make it not do that? I'm thinking it might have to do with the type -- obviously I can't just use "int" of `s`, but I might try to round it to one decimal place. Currently the differences are actually slightly visible.

Comment: Please don't describe your `while` loop: post an [MCVE]. Also, if you can see a relative difference of anything <1e-2, that's amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since floating point numbers are stored in finite precision, and most architectures use a binary internal representation, `0.2` can not be expressed exactly. You end up with a number that is really `0.2 + ε`, where `ε` is some small error on the order of `2e-16`.

As you iterate, the error adds up. Even `3.2` is not really `3.2`. It's actually `3.2 + ε`, but the `print` function knows to ignore errors smaller than a certain threshold. So at `3 + 9 * ds`, you are printing `4.8 + 9ε`.

You can not avoid having some error, but you can minimize it so that each number prints with the minimum error rather than a constantly increasing one. Rounding the floats to two decimal places is one way, but it does not magically enable your platform to represent `0.2` and its multiples exactly.

The most common way to improve accuracy is to change the way your loop is formulated. Instead of writing a decimal as you did

```
ds = 0.2  # includes ε
for i in range(10):
    print(3 + i * ds)
```

Use the rational representation to get you to the same point:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(3 + i // 5)
```

Another way, if you have a fixed precision, is to work with integers:

```
ds = 2
for i in range(10):
    n = 30 + i * ds
    print(f'{n // 10}.{n % 10}')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Floating point numbers](https://betterprogramming.pub/floating-point-numbers-are-weird-in-python-heres-how-to-fix-them-51336e4ad51a) `round` is your goto for this situation.

```
s = 3 
ds = .2 
while s <= 5:
    s+=ds 
    print(round(s,2))
```

output

```
3.2
3.4
3.6
3.8
4.0
4.2
4.4
4.6
4.8
5.0
```